# 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' en Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize this json

```
json=[
  {
    "id_factura": 85,
    "fecha": "2019-08-07T19:00:00-05:00",
    "cliente": {
      "persona_cedula_persona": "0705",
      "tipocliente": {
        "id_tipo_cliente": 1,
        "tipo_cliente": "PRUEBA"
      }
    },
    "lines": [
      {
        "id_detalle": 30,
        "nombre_producto": "bidon de agua",
        "cantidad": 2.0,
        "precio": 3.0
      },
      {
        "id_detalle": 31,
        "nombre_producto": "botellas de agua",
        "cantidad": 12.0,
        "precio": 7.0
      },
      {
        "id_detalle": 32,
        "nombre_producto": "BOTELLA PEQUEÃ‘A",
        "cantidad": 5.0,
        "precio": 3.0
      },
      {
        "id_detalle": 33,
        "nombre_producto": "botella MEDIANA 5 LITROS",
        "cantidad": 12.0,
        "precio": 7.0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

to this class

```
class Factura
{
    public int id_factura { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public  Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public IList<lines> lines{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Please show us your full code and what error you are getting? In visual studio an option is available to convert JSON payload into C# class. You need to Copy the JSON payload, create a new class and go under edit and click on paste special. You will be able to see an option as "PASTE as JSON Class"

Comment: Try this, at this line: public IList<lines> lines{ get; set; }  change <lines> to <line> and rename "lines" class to "line"

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, using the [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library which is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET, you can deserialize your JSON string by the following code snippet provided:

A working example can be found at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EexYYf

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json=@"[{'id_factura':85,'fecha':'2019-08-07T19:00:00-05:00','cliente':{'persona_cedula_persona':'0705','tipocliente':{'id_tipo_cliente':1,'tipo_cliente':'PRUEBA'}},'lines':[{'id_detalle':30,'nombre_producto':'bidon de agua','cantidad':2,'precio':3},{'id_detalle':31,'nombre_producto':'botellas de agua','cantidad':12,'precio':7},{'id_detalle':32,'nombre_producto':'BOTELLA PEQUEÃ‘A','cantidad':5,'precio':3},{'id_detalle':33,'nombre_producto':'botella MEDIANA 5 LITROS','cantidad':12,'precio':7}]}]";
        var Sresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

        foreach(var result in Sresponse)
        {
            //Get your data here from the deserialization
        Console.WriteLine("Factura: "+result.id_factura);
        Console.WriteLine("Fecha: "+result.fecha);
        Console.WriteLine("Cliente Persona Cedula Persona: "+result.cliente.persona_cedula_persona);            
        }

    }
}

public class Tipocliente
{
    public int id_tipo_cliente { get; set; }
    public string tipo_cliente { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public string persona_cedula_persona { get; set; }
    public Tipocliente tipocliente { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public int id_detalle { get; set; }
    public string nombre_producto { get; set; }
    public double cantidad { get; set; }
    public double precio { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id_factura { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public List<Line> lines { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Factura: 85
Fecha: 8/8/2019 12:00:00 AM
Cliente Persona Cedula Persona: 0705
```